# How can I find whether a process is in deadlock or is waiting for I/O

Tags: windows, linux, unix, operating-system, kernel

Asked by an Interviewer:
How can we find if an application has become non responsive due to a deadlock or due to wait on some IO?
Can anybody comment any general way of doing this, or if various provides some specific ways of doing this?
This is an OS related thing I believe so I am not tagging any language here.

EDIT: I would like to know about the techniques and the APIs as well to do this. So that i can run a monitoring program if i wish.

Answer (score 3):

On linux I would use `sar -u 1`. If the `%iowait` column is high, then the application is probably waiting for IO

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can attach WinDbg and then execute `!analyze -v -hang` which will work out which thread is waiting on I/O. (The only time I used this I got lucky and it was an open call which was waiting, so I got to find out the file name very quickly.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there are many possible design as solutions.

If in your application, u use open() with lockf() or flock() to lock the resource.     So the next time another process (or the same process) attempt to flock() the same file again it will be blocked.

If u open a file with LOCK_NB (see "man -s 2 flock in Ubuntu) non-blocking locks, and then returned with EWOULDBLOCK error, then u can deduce that the file is locked.

To identify all the locked files in the OS, one way is to do a "lsof" to see all the opened files, and from the filename and using fcntl() u can identify the types of locks held.

Many possible alternative designs: eg, for Oracle database there is a concept called waiter list to list all the waiters waiting on the existing locked records.   Because of this sophisticated design, automatic deadlock detection is also possible.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_deadlock.htm

Other techniques are described in general OS courses:

http://lovingod.host.sk/tanenbaum/Recovery-from-Deadlock.html

Answer (score -1):

On Linux you can attach `gdb` to a running process. It'll stop the process at the point where is is running, with `bt` you'll get the back-trace. You can also get the thread info of all running threads, switch between them and look at the back-trace of each using `info threads; thread N; bt`.

Another very useful tool under Linux is `strace` which traces system calls, you can also attach this to running processes. The `-c` option shows you profiling information of the system calls done by the program.